# prismjs not working between different routes using vuerouter in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, prismjs

I've imported `prism.js` globally in `main.js` file.
Code block syntax highlighting working fine in Home components, but after routing to another page using `vue-router`, there is no effect.

in `main.js`

```
// Global Import
import 'prismjs/prism.js'
import 'prismjs/components/prism-swift.min.js' // swift lang
import './theme/prism-swift-theme.css'
```

in my about page component...

```
<pre><code class="language-swift">
  private func setupSubviews() {
   let value = "Loading code block";
  }
</code></pre>
```

Unable to understand what's wrong here. Is there any way I can import `node_modules` prismjs files globally? I thought keeping `main.js` will work fine, but it's not adding globally between routes...

Answer (score 0):

Once you install it with npm the best approach is to import it whenever it is used in each component seperately with `import Prism from 'prismjs'`. Just make sure to use the `Prism.highlightAll()` method in the component where you're using prism after the DOM is rendered whether in `mount()` hook or in the `updated` [Vuejs hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) using `nextTick` method to make sure all the DOM is rendered before using prism. So in your case you should use it this way:

```js
import Prism from "prismjs"

updated: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  })
}
```

make sure you call highlightAll in yor components seperately and not globaly.